# Cannot get attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `HTML`:

```
<input class="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true" data-photoShootId="@item.PhotoShootItemId" />
```

And the following `jQuery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.file_upload').uploadifive({
            //*snip*

            'formData': {
                'PhotoShootItemId': $(this).data('photoShootId')
            },

            //*snip*
        });
    });
</script>
```

The script itself functions with no issues.

My problem is I cannot seem to get the `data-photoShootId` value from the `file_upload` element. I simply get `undefined` in my POST data. If I replace the `.data` call with a constant value, it works fine.

If I use `$(this).attr` and `photoShootId="@item.PhotoShootItemId"`, I get the same result.

Comment: you can check rendered HTML to see if `data-photoShootId` actually has any value in it.

Comment: Try using `$(this).attr('data-photoShootId')`

Comment: what is the value of `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `this` in your code does not refer to the element you are instatiating the plugin on, but the `window`.

To get an attribute from the element to use in the plugin call you need to loop over each individually:

```
$('.file_upload').each(function() {
    $(this).uploadifive({
        //*snip*
        'formData': {
            'PhotoShootItemId': $(this).data('photoShootId')
        },
        //*snip*
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set the data attribute like this :-

```
<input class="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true" data-photoshootid="@item.PhotoShootItemId" />
```

And get the attribute like this

```
$(this).data('photoshootid')
```

Avoid using uppercase letters for data attributes

Comment: Didn't answer my question, but great advice, thanks!